# In co-located caching, how is determined the location of a key?

Tags: azure, distributed-caching, azure-caching

This a design question about the Caching component, I can see two approaches in determining where is the data:

- Each role instance maintains a table containing the entire set of keys, tracking the corresponding instance holding the data.
- The location of the data is determined by the hash code of the key.

In the first case, it would mean that it's important to keep a reasonable set of keys.
In the second case, that testing the existence of a key would generate a network round trip...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is 2), it utilize hash to determine the location, maybe consistent hashing.

And I think yes, testing the existence of a key would generate a network I/O, but I don't think it needs to call all you co-location server since from the hash it should know which server contains your data and just need to connect to it.